# vercel error generating static pages with next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I kepp getting this error when deploying on vercel:

```
> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:

/
/: /en
/: /pl
/_error: /404
/_error: /500
/_error: /en/404
/_error: /en/500
/_error: /pl/404
/_error: /pl/500
/listing/[slugId]: /pl/listing/1
/listing/[slugId]: /pl/listing/10
/listing/[slugId]: /pl/listing/100
/listing/[slugId]: /pl/listing/11
/listing/[slugId]: /pl/listing/12
```

etc.

and the error is

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
    at exports.useMemo (/vercel/path0/node_modules/.pnpm/react@18.2.0/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:208)
    at Object.useDehydratedState (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/.pnpm/@trpc+react-query@10.0.0-rc.3_y6yjugiwomqyvbrpc2lz4flpyi/node_modules/@trpc/react-query/dist/createHooksInternal-92c57b9a.mjs:379:29)
    at WithTRPC (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/834.js:988:40)
    at Yd (/vercel/path0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.0.2-canary.2_mk5yftg2men2cn3ayx4t7ddtvy/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:98:272)
```

BTW, I'm not using useMemo anywhere in my code

1. I have same .env variables locally and on preview environment on vercel.
2. Local build goes fine without errors
3. All pages are inside /pages
4. on static pages /listing... fallback is set to false
5. all dependencies updated to latest (including next@13)

Any thoughts or ideas that my help?

Comment: does running `build` command locally, ends successfully?

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A as I mentioned, no errors, all pages rendered succesfully

Comment: What about running `next build && next export`  locally? Also, are you using `@trpc/react-query` in those pages?